# How to insert a both an image and text in a Folium marker

Tags: python, marker, folium

I have recently developed a program that takes the data on works of architecture of a specific city from 'Archinform', and then proceeds to scrape the data needed to then plot the map.
I have been inserting the info about the building as a tooltip and the image as the marker.
How can I also add the building name to the marker?
I'll add my code below

```
arch_map = folium.Map(location=coord_città, zoom_start=11)
#creating map with folium with tooltips which are the information of the place and markers which are the images

for lat, lng,name,label in zip(valid_xcoords, valid_ycoords, google_names, project_info):
    if lat != 0:
        html = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">'.format
        encoded = base64.b64encode(open(name+' '+cit+'.jpg', 'rb').read()).decode()
        iframe = folium.IFrame(html(encoded), width=300, height=150)
        tooltip = folium.Popup(iframe)
        icon=folium.IFrame('<i class="fas fa-archway"></i>')
        folium.Marker([lat, lng],tooltip=label,popup=tooltip,icon=folium.Icon(color='orange',icon='university',prefix='fa')).add_to(arch_map)

arch_map.save('Mappa di '+cit+'.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Iframe, you can use different HTML tags. In your case, you can use the figure and figurecaption tags to add the building name in your marker :

```
html = '<figure>'
encoded = base64.b64encode(open(name+' '+cit+'.jpg', 'rb').read()).decode()
html += '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">'.format(encoded)
html += '<figcaption>{}</figcaption></figure>'.format(building_name)
```